# How to configure and connect to a remote MongoDB server on a hosting provider server?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I've been trying to establish a connection to my MongoDB on my Cloud VPS hosting server.

I'm hosting my website on a Cloud VPS running Ubuntu 16.04 (my hosting provider is InMotion hosting if anyone knows them).

1. I've installed MongoDB on the server.
2. I've edited the `/etc/mongo.conf` file to `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`
3. Created an admin user `db.createUser({user: "XXXXX",pwd: "XXXXX",roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"],mechanisms:[ "SCRAM-SHA-1" ]})`
4. Restarted the service and checked the status that it is `Active`

Now, I'm trying to connect using RoboMongo, putting the server IP, user, and password and it doesn't connect.

To be able to connect via SSH I had to generate a public SSH key and then load the private key to PuTTY, so I even tried to connect RoboMongo with SSH. I've attached screenshots of the settings I've tried in RoboMongo.

When trying to connect with SSH I get this error:

```
Failed to create SSH tunnel to XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:22.

Error:
Authentication by key (PATH/id_rsa.ppk) failed (Error -16)
```

When trying without SSH I get this:

```
Cannot connect to the MongoDB at XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:27017.

Error:
Network is unreachable.
```

[image: Robomongo SSH settings]

[image: Robomongo Authentication settings]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Sohan, I've added both cases error messages to the question

Comment: First try without SSH, making sure connection is passed. Have you check if port is exposed i mean is it whitelisted on your cloud server. Also try to access using domain name instead of IP

Comment: I've tried without SSH, I've posted the error also. How do I check if the port is exposed? I don't have the domain name...

Comment: I've tried running these: `iptables -A INPUT -s <ip-address> -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip-address> -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` it didn't help